# Postgresql - how to run pg_cron schedules for non-priviledged user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, pg-cron

We use [pg_cron extension](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) in out Postgresql 13 environment. There is a demand from users to create their own schedules for particular jobs.
Our current implementation is that cron tables/functions are in "cron" schema owned by postgres user. I am sure I could do:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA cron TO user1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE cron.job TO user1;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA cron TO user1;
```

but I do not like this attitude - it is a security exeption I I would try to avoid this.
Any ideas (on abstract level) how to do it?

Comment: Use a `SECURITY DEFINER` function as explained here [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)?